# Two classes include each other, what's wrong with the next code?

Tags: c++, class

I have 2 classes, "A" and "B"

### A.h

```
#ifndef _A_H__
#define _A_H__
#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
    struct Test 
    {
        int qq;
    };
    B *b;
};
#endif
```

### B.h

```
#ifndef _B_H__
#define _B_H__
#include "A.h"
class A;
class B
{
public:
    A *a;
    A::Test* qq;
};
#endif
```

But, this cannot compile success. Who can tell me `A::Test*` how to as a member in `B`

Comment: what is the compilation error?

Comment: why tag `c` when it's a `C++` concept? [Removed]

Comment: Use an undefined "A" on here "A::Test* qq;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a circular dependency, header file `A.h` needs `B.h` which needs `A.h` and so on in eternity.

The only way to break the cycle is to not include one of the header files in the other.

In your case, the header file `B.h` really needs the `A.h` header file, since the class `B` uses members of class `A`, so you need to change so that header file `A.h` doesn't include `B.h`. This is simple, because class `A` doesn't really use or need to know anything about the contents of class `B`, only that class `B` exists, so change `A.h` like this:

```
#ifndef _A_H__
#define _A_H__

// Declare that class B exists
class B;

class A
{
public:
    struct Test 
    {
        int qq;
    };

    // The compiler knows that a class B exists, so we can have a pointer
    // to that class here. To declare a pointer to some type, the compiler
    // doesn't need the actual definition of the type, just know that the
    // type exists.
    B *b;
};
#endif
```

Answer (score -2):

Write B.h like following:

```
#ifndef _B_H__
#define _B_H__

class A;
class B
{
public:
    A *a;
    A::Test* qq;
};
#endif
```

Comment: That won't compile. You need the definition of `A` to use nested names like `A::Test`.